# How do you get an iframe to load content from a link on another page?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Here's the scenario:

I have a link on "page1.html" that i want to get displayed on an iframe of another link "page2.html" .

How do I do this?

Comment: actually I just realized that script is to resize the iframe dynamically based on content within it.  That's another issue and that particular script doesn't work.

Comment: Please fix the question to remove unnecessary noise. Don't post two questions as one.

Answer (score 0):

**Fourth and final try!**

The problem with your page is the following

Your problem is that your link [See adoptable dogs] points to http://hssv.convio.net/PageServer?pagename=adoption_available?http://adopt.hssv.org/search/searchResults.asp?task=search&searchid=&advanced=&s=adoption&animalType=3%2C16&statusID=3&submitbtn=Find+Animals

When I go to 
http://hssv.convio.net/PageServer?pagename=adoption_available,
I'm redirected to 
http://hssv.convio.net/site/PageServer?pagename=page_not_found

Therefore I assume the correct link is http://hssv.convio.net/site/PageServer?pagename=adoption_available (yup, that loaded a page correctly, you were missing /site/ within the link)

Now the second part of your problem. Your page that contains an iframe expected the name of the page to load into the iframe to be everything after the '?', which was fine before since you were't using any other params in the URL (actually not fine, since it breaks easily)

so your link should be (note that the url passed as a parameter should be url encoded)

http://hssv.convio.net/site/PageServer?pagename=adoption_available&content=http%3A%2F%2Fadopt.hssv.org%2Fsearch%2FsearchResults.asp%3Ftask%3Dsearch%26searchid%3D%26advanced%3D%26s%3Dadoption%26animalType%3D3%2C16%26statusID%3D3%26submitbtn%3DFind%2BAnimals

And your page containing the iframe should modify LoadContent to the following.

```
function LoadContent() {
  var url = getParams()['content'];
  if (url) {
    LoadIFrame(url);
  }
}

function getParams() {

  var paramMap = {};
  if (location.search.length == 0) {
    return paramMap;
  }
  var parts = location.search.substring(1).split("&");

  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i ++) {
    var component = parts[i].split("=");
    paramMap [decodeURIComponent(component[0])] = decodeURIComponent(component[1]);
  }
  return paramMap;
}
```

Lastly, I don't want to sound rude, but it seems like you need to do some studying before you are assigned to modify these pages. These are all very basic concepts of HTML, HTTP, and JS. Some debugging would easily identify your problem and it had nothing to do with what you asked initially, it was simply that you modified code without a clue to what it was doing...

Comment: That would work, but I am referring to having a link on page1.html that goes to page2.html (where page2.html has the iframe) 

How do I get the link on page1.html to load content into page2.html's iframe.  I'm not referring to page1.html having an iframe.  I'm referring to page2.html has an iframe and that iframe has content that can dynamically change from whatever link is clicked on from page1.html.  

Does that make sense?

And I agree, crappy code, but I was desparate :)

Comment: That's incorrect. I think I'm phrasing this wrong.  If you go to http://hssv.convio.net/site/PageServer?pagename=updated_home and click on the images (dogs cats or rabbits) you will see what the link is supposed to do.

Comment: I saw the page, and your code is doing what I suggested (using JS instead of PHP). Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: What would the javascript look like.  I'm not savvy with javascript or PHP so would be looking for "plug n play".  Let me know.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, that page I gave you was an example.  were moving the entire website.  When I moved the site over, the script stopped working.  I'm stumped as to why.  If you notice by going to the URL above and clicking on dog/cat/rabbit, it goes to a completely different server.  Now everythings on one server and it doesnt work. The new site is http://hssv.convio.net/site/PageServer?pagename=updated_home_test.  click on adopt a dog, cat and kitten test & you will see it break.  The page it's supposed to goto is http://hssv.convio.net/site/PageServer?pagename=adoption_available and has the iframe

Comment: I appreciate your help and criticisms.  As I stated before I'm not too savvy with JS and yes would love to learn it and I know it's one of the basic 3 languages I need to learn.  However, I placed the script in the page and followed your instructions, but it doesn't refresh the iframe.

Comment: I should be more specific.  The "Cats and Kittens Test" link is the only link I changed at this point to see if it would work.  No such luck.  The dog and rabbit link is not changed at this point, just the cat one.  It doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: I can't keep debugging your page for you James, sorry. You did not use the link I gave you. Pay close attention to both, you have a ? instead of an &. I loaded your http://hssv.convio.net/site/PageServer?pagename=adoption_available&content=http://adopt.hssv.org/search/searchResults.asp%3Ftask%3Dsearch%26searchid%3D%26advanced%3D%26s%3Dadoption%26animalType%3D3,16%26statusID%3D3%26submitbtn%3DFind%2BAnimals and I got the following message: `missing ] in index expression
[Break On This Error] var tempobj=document.all? document.all...document.getElementById(iframeids[i]) line 115`.

Comment: Install Firebug (with firerfox) and run it on your page. Learn how to debug and add breakpoints to see code execution.